# How to save http request to django?

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I have a device that do some calculations and then i want to send it with help of request to my site:

```
import requests

params = {'data1': '47237582'}

r =requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/", data = params)
print(r)
```

I have a django site. How can i save the value of my request for later display?

```
def read(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        msg = request.GET['data1']
```

And how can i save it to database?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/

Answer (score 0):

- First, create a model called **Message**, fields maybe: **msg** and **from**, it actually depends on how you want to store the msg,
- Then after getting the msg with `msg = request.GET['data1']` store the msg with `msg_obj = Message.objects.create(msg=msg, ...other-fields if any)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are gonna have different keys (i.e columns) for each request, then I say you use **MongoDB**, which will allow you save different set of key-values in a single document.